# Keycloak Admin UI panel page Stuck at Loading Ui the Admin Ui

Tags: authentication, keycloak, issue-tracking

Hello to all I got the following code to setup keycloak in Docker.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder

# Enable health and metrics support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true

# Configure a database vendor
ENV KC_DB=mysql

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
# for demonstration purposes only, please make sure to use proper certificates in production instead
RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias serve>RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

# change these values to point to a running postgres instance
ENV KC_DB=mysql
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/keyCloak
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=root
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=password
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=ipV4
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

and an nginx keycloak.conf to apply https:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    client_max_body_size 25m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8447/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
        # Error handling configuration
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        # Error handling configuration
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    listen 82;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Ok so im able to access the keycloak throught this url:https://example.com/  that shows me good the Keycloak page but when I click on Administration panel it takes me to this: https://example.com/admin/master/console/  that appears me a loading spinner and a message Loading the Admin Ui.   Anyone had any same issues?  Maybe its version problem because in older versions it used to work well showing me the admin panel

Im tried to change to older versions but still got stuck and i dont know what is the problem